# use nginx proxy resolves cross-domain issues but it still exist cross-domain？

Tags: nginx, vue.js, axios, koa

I opened a service with koa locally for user registration.

The service is http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/user/register

Front-end service is http://127.0.0.1:8083/#/signup

So I used nginx for proxy_pass， like this

[image: nginx setting]

Chrome give me the following tips

[image: Chrome clonse]

But the request was sent successfully，the database stores the corresponding data。why？

[image: request]

my Front-end code is

```
import axios from 'axios';
import qs from 'qs';

const host = 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/';

const registerUrl = `${host}user/register`;

class User {
    // user register
    static async register(params) {
        const result = await axios.post(registerUrl, qs.stringify(params));
        return result;
    }
}

export default User;
```

Comment: Stuffs seems mixed here. On which port listens your backend nodejs service? On which one listens nginx (for backend proxy pass) ? How is served the frontend? Statically through nginx ?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder that this works without specifying the route (URI) you want to have a proxy for ... you should do it like:

```
server {
  listen 8081;
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8083/api;
  }
}
```

OR adding the necessary headers in nginx - this would then allow you to use one port for front end (8081) serving and another for the backend API (8083) without having problems with CORS:

```
server {
  listen 8083;
  location / {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,POST,MERGE,PATCH,DELETE,PUT';
  }
}
```

Code/Configuration not tested... but I hope that makes sense for you